# How to edit a Form via actual Code and not the Properties menu?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, forms, properties

Where do I find the ACTUAL code of my Forms?

You know, the stuff you set in the properties menu, where is the code for that? I can't find it!
Im new to using Forms so this question is most liekely the dumbest thing you heard in the last weeks and I know that so pelase just tell me how to do it! Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for the `FormName.Designer.cs` file for any given form?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [(Why/How) should I use .designer files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911783/why-how-should-i-use-designer-files)

Answer (score 0):

In `<FormName>.designer.cs` file.

Open the file and expand the block

```
#region Windows Form Designer generated code
private void InitializeComponent()
```